# Splitting word document to pages using JACOB

Tags: java, jacob

I have been trying to split a word document to pages. A through POC that led to the fact that this cannot be done through Apache POI, and consequently made me resort to JACOB to invoke MS Word as a proxy to achieve such transformation.

I have made some reasonable advancements with my code, now I am able to open a document, search, replace, and so on. However I am unable to get the "page" bookmark

```
            ActiveXComponent oDocuments = oWord.getPropertyAsComponent("Documents");
        ActiveXComponent oDocument = oDocuments.invokeGetComponent("Open", new Variant(sInputDoc), new Variant(false));
        ActiveXComponent oSelection = oWord.getPropertyAsComponent("Selection");

        ActiveXComponent oBookmarks = oSelection.getPropertyAsComponent("Bookmarks");
        int bookMarksnumber = oBookmarks.getProperty("Count").getInt();
        System.out.println(bookMarksnumber);
```

This always returns 0 (If the same can be achieved using POI I am open to all suggestions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this to achieve bookmarks

```
ActiveXComponent oBookmarks = oDocument.getPropertyAsComponent("Bookmarks");
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: Thanks for the update, this one worked for me, still my problem is not resolved unfourtunatly